# Random Number Objective-C (linux)

Tags: objective-c, linux

Now, I know that this is a simple question for MacOS, but when I compile a code with 'arc4random % n' in it, I just get an error log in Terminal saying:

```
main.m:9: error: ‘arc4random’ undeclared (first use in this function)
main.m:9: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
main.m:9: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

and I use:

```
gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -lgnustep-base main.m -o main
```

to compile it

and here's my code (if it helps) :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
        NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        int number, guess;

    number = arc4random() % 101;

    while (!guess == number) {  
        NSLog (@"Please guess a number between 1 and 100");
        scanf ("%i", &guess);

        if  (guess < number) {
            NSLog (@"Sorry, guessed too low!");
        }

        else if (guess > number) {
            NSLog (@"Sorry, guessed too high!");
            }
    }

        NSLog (@"You guessed correct!");

        [pool drain];
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `>>` and `<<` are not comparison operators. `arc4random` is a function, you need to call it (and have the proper header included).

Comment: Please compile with the `-Wall` program argument given to your GCC compiler.

Comment: @starykenvitch Can you please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider using `clang` instead of `gcc`

Use

```
clang -fno-objc-arc main.m -framework Foundation -o main
```

Also I'd use `arc4random_uniform(101)` instead of `arc4random() % 101`, since the former is bias free.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Strange, clang is still unable to find arc4random on my Ubuntu computer. https://github.com/mcandre/ios7crypt/tree/d6dae90ab1bdddfae3867e9eca4447f7affa9582/objc

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

1. Your use of >> and <<, these are not valid comparison operators. This will compile, but not perform what you expect. You either need to use > (greater than), >= (greater than or equals), < (less than) or <= (less than or equals).
2. Your compile error is due to your use of arc4random. This is a function, but you've not used it as such. You need to change your line to

   ```
   number = arc4random() % 101;
   ```
3. Not 100% sure on this, but %i in your scanf looks like it should be %d

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I know I made some basic mistakes, but I just wanted to test the gnustep compiler out, then fix the problems. I tried 'arc4random() % 101;' instead of 'arc4random() %101', but it didn't help, sadly

Comment: beside arc4random() you will need to link libbsd, -lbsd, or just use random()

Comment: @Frith-MacDonald Thanks, I'll try with random()